# Change Zlib version in android project

Tags: android, compression, native, zlib, android-native-library

Recently I found that [archive-patcher](https://github.com/google/archive-patcher) library isn't working in android 12, and then I found that android 12 used the new version of Zlib that is changed a little and the problem is for that.

Is it possible to explicitly link my own zip version in my project?

Comment: Did you find the solution? meet the same problem.

Comment: Yes, I forgot this post; I will add the answer as soon as possible

Comment: problem is fixed in my last PR in Google archive-patcher by changing the Zlib version; you can see more :
https://github.com/google/archive-patcher/pull/193